# solr group query to return results along with normal results

Tags: solr, grouping

i am trying a group query in solr which is

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/venue/select?q=allText%3A%22holiday+inn%22&rows=100&wt=json&indent=true&group=true&group.query=title:(holiday%20inn)&group.limit=10
```

this gives me results where "holiday inn" matches in title, allText field is a copy field which has values from fields title,location and description

what i tried was setting

```
group.main=true
```

but after doing this it gives me all the records without the grouping.
what i want is all records with the groupings

thanks in advance

the query i used after the suggestion was

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/venue/select?wt=json&indent=true&q=*%3A*&wt=json&rows=100000&fq=title:%22holiday%20inn%22&fl=title&group=true&group.field=title&group.limit=100000
```

and this gave me result

```
"responseHeader":{
"status":0,
"QTime":30,
"params":{
  "q":"allText:(holiday inn)",
  "indent":"true",
  "fl":"title",
  "group.limit":"100000",
  "fq":"title:\"holiday inn\"",
  "rows":"100000",
  "wt":["json",
    "json"],
  "group.field":"title",
  "group":"true"}},
"grouped":{
"title":{
  "matches":1,
  "groups":[{
      "groupValue":"holiday",
      "doclist":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
          {
            "id":209,
            "title":"Holiday Inn"}]
      }}]}}]
```

along with the group result which is correct can i also get the result for q=allText:(holiday inn) which without the group gives 25 matched results??

Answer (score 0):

This is a working sample Group QUERY

```
q=*%3A*&wt=json&rows=100000&fq=reported_dt:[2015-10-25T14:55:13.000Z%20TO%202015-12-04T08:38:08.000Z]&fl=reported_dt project_status_val&group=true&group.field=project_number&group.limit=100000
```

The difference i see you dont Have a numeric group field in your QUERY.

Comment: i have added the result set and the exact query, the group result is coming fine its just that i need the other result set along with the group set. is it possible?